# How to use a set of Pressure Transducer to mimic pitot static tube for VTOL vertical airspeed indicator?

Tags: aerodynamics, takeoff, unmanned-aerial-vehicle, vtol, pitot-static

May i know if i have 3 pressure transducer, 1 facing upwards and the other downwards to measure the vertical velocity of a VTOL (Vertical Takeoff and Landing aircraft) and another 1 on the nose of the aircraft, do i still need a pressure transducer to mimic a Static port to measure the climb rate? Since i already have 2 pointing upwards and downwards. For your kind advise, thanks!

Comment: Unless it's a rocket there's really not enough vertical air speed to make meaningful measurements. All you are measuring is just wind noise. You have much better results using a accelerometer or a radar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be measuring any static pressures because facing the transducers into the sense direction produces dynamic positive pressure which is not subject to temperature compensation or air density corrections at altitude. A Vertical Speed Indicator works by taking static pressure and a calibrated leak inside the instrument to show your climb rate. You can't replicate this using the system you describe.

Even using your suggestion of adding another transducer for static is not enough. You need a rate of change which, as stated above, is normally provided by a calibrated leak inside the VSI.

If you want to explore further options of measuring position in 3d space that don't involve pressure transducers, I suggest looking at gyros and accelerometers.